# Error while loading route: ReferenceError: CalendarData is not defined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to uses functions to define the model properties, but I'm getting an error in the route. I'm creating a calendar to use in a datepicker sorted by the month name. Is it my controller, my model, or something else?

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("calendar");
    this.resource("about");        
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('calendar');
    }
});

App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return CalendarData;
    },
    serializer: function(model){
        return {month: model.get('month')};
    }
});

// calendar controller


// calendar data
App.CalendarData = Ember.Object.extend({
    today: function(){
        var Today = new Date();
        return Today;
    },

    date: function(){
        var Date = Today.getDate();
        return Date;
    },

    month: function(){
        // this array gives month names
        var MonthA = new Array();
        MonthA[0] = "January";
        MonthA[1] = "February";
        MonthA[2] = "March";
        MonthA[3] = "April";
        MonthA[4] = "May";
        MonthA[5] = "June";
        MonthA[6] = "July";
        MonthA[7] = "August";
        MonthA[8] = "September";
        MonthA[9] = "October";
        MonthA[10] = "November";
        MonthA[11] = "December";
        var Month = Today.getMonth();
        return MonthA[Month];
    },

    dow: function(){
        var Weekday = new Array();
        Weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        Weekday[1] = "Monday";
        Weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        Weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        Weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        Weekday[5] = "Friday";
        Weekday[6] = "Saturday";
        var dow = Today.getDay();
        return Weekday[dow];
    },

    year: function(){
        var Year = Today.getYear();
        return Year;
    }

});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/foqok/1/

Comment: Just a hunch, but maybe CalendarData is not defined?

Comment: Wow! It says that right in my title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are returning CalendarData as if it is a global or scoped variable, but it should be part of the App context. Did you try return App.CalendarData?

P.S. I wanted to add this as small comment but I dont have the required 50 rep :-(

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for accepting the answer :) Finally building up some rep haha.